# Simplest way to persist/aggregate logs of multiple docker containers?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I am looking for the simplest way to aggregate logs in my homelab environment.

Recently i had issues with containers, did some stuff, restarted the containers. And lost my logs. Now i know i can do `docker [service] logs XX > container_log.log` but i want that to be something that is done automatically in any way.

I was already thinking about the ELK Stack, but i don't want to setup that much stuff to be honest. Something that would save the logs all the time in a specified folder on the host would be enough for me.

I also know that docker already saves the logs in a dedicated folder, but that is only for the runtime of the specific container. That is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Start by reading the Docker [Logging Guide](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) to understand how log drivers work. Then I recommend looking at the `fluentd` driver. You'll need to configure a server that will capture the logs and store them, but that's not overly difficult. You don't need to jump to Elasticsearch, but it's just another output connector for Fluentd when you're ready.

Comment: An alternative to Fluentd could be Filebeat's autodiscovery https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html with a docker-provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP here, for anyone in the future, I did this:

You have to start a `syslog-ng` server. I did this with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  syslog-ng:
    image: linuxserver/syslog-ng:3.36.1 
    container_name: syslog-ng
    environment:
      - PUID=0
      - PGID=0
      - TZ= #Your Timezone here
    volumes:
      - /srv/syslog/config:/config
      - /srv/syslog/logs:/var/log
    ports:
      - 514:5514/udp
      - 601:6601/tcp
      - 6514:6514/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - syslog
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"

networks:
  syslog:
    external: true
```

After that you have to change the logging settings for every docker daemon that is running in your datacenter/docker-swarm.

Edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the following stuff with the appropriate IP address:

```json
{
    "log-driver": "syslog",
    "log-opts": {
        "syslog-address": "udp://127.0.0.1:514",
        "tag": "{{.Name}}"
    }
}
```

If you want to have all your logs sorted in folders by **year/month/day** you need to edit the `syslog-ng.conf` and add this part:

```
  file("/var/log/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}.log" create-dirs(yes));
```